# Obtain all WiFis' SSIDs & BSSIDs

Tags: linux, awk, ssid, bssid

How can I get all BSSIDs of the iw and iwinfo commands' output? Here are iw and iwinfo commands to get all the SSIDs. iw:

```
iw dev wlan0 scan 2>/dev/null | awk '
/SSID: / {
  if (!seen[$0]++) {
    printf "\""
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) if (i == 2) printf $i
    else printf " " $i
    printf "\" "
  }
}
'
```

iwinfo:

```
iwinfo wlan0 scan | awk '
/ESSID: ".*"/ {
  ORS = " "
  if (!seen[$0]++) for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print $i
}
'
```

Current awk output:

> "WiFi-1" "WiFi-2" "WiFi-3" "WiFi-4" "WiFi-5" ...

iw console output:

```
BSS 01:23:45:67:89:AB(on wlan0)
        TSF: 128785915910 usec (1d, 11:46:25)
        freq: 2437
        beacon interval: 200 TUs
        capability: ESS ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0421)
        signal: -71.00 dBm
        last seen: 990 ms ago
        Information elements from Probe Response frame:
        SSID: WiFi-1
        Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 6.0 9.0 11.0* 12.0 18.0
        DS Parameter set: channel 6
        Country: SK     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
                Channels [1 - 13] @ 20 dBm
        ERP: <no flags>
        Extended supported rates: 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
        WMM:     * Parameter version 1
                 * BE: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 3
                 * BK: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 7
                 * VI: CW 7-15, AIFSN 2, TXOP 3008 usec
                 * VO: CW 3-7, AIFSN 2, TXOP 1504 usec
BSS CD:EF:A0:A1:A2:A3(on wlan0)
        TSF: 2381690679244 usec (27d, 13:34:50)
        freq: 2467
        beacon interval: 200 TUs
        capability: ESS ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0421)
        signal: -94.00 dBm
        last seen: 90 ms ago
        Information elements from Probe Response frame:
        SSID: WiFi-2
        Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 6.0 9.0 11.0* 12.0 18.0
        DS Parameter set: channel 12
        Country: SK     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
                Channels [1 - 13] @ 20 dBm
        ERP: <no flags>
        Extended supported rates: 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
        WMM:     * Parameter version 1
                 * BE: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 3
                 * BK: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 7
                 * VI: CW 7-15, AIFSN 2, TXOP 3008 usec
                 * VO: CW 3-7, AIFSN 2, TXOP 1504 usec
```

iwinfo console output:

```
Cell 01 - Address: 01:23:45:67:89:AB
          ESSID: "WiFi-1"
          Mode: Master  Channel: 11
          Signal: -49 dBm  Quality: 61/70
          Encryption: WPA2 PSK (CCMP)

Cell 02 - Address: CD:EF:A0:A1:A2:A3
          ESSID: "WiFi-2"
          Mode: Master  Channel: 11
          Signal: -53 dBm  Quality: 57/70
          Encryption: WPA2 PSK (CCMP)
```

I would like to get the following output using the awk:

> "01:23:45:67:89:AB" "CD:EF:A0:A1:A2:A3" ...

What is the correct way to capture all the BSSIDs using the Awk for both libs (iw & iwinfo)?

Comment: `{ iw dev ...; iwinfo ...; } | awk ...` maybe

Comment: Show some output of the `iw` and `iwinfo` commands (i.e. the sample input to the awk command you want to write) and the desired output from the awk command given that input.

Comment: Why do you say you want to capture the `BSSID`s yet your required output is the MAC addresses? Why do you want to run 2 commands that appear to give the same results?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - BSSIDs are the MAC addresses found in the iw & iwinfo scan output. I would like to know awk commands for both libs, since I have two devices where I cannot install iw/iwinfo and vice versa. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
{ cat iw_output; cat iwinfo_output; } |
awk 'match($0,/([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}/,a) && !seen[a[0]]++{print a[0]}'
01:23:45:67:89:AB
CD:EF:A0:A1:A2:A3
```

or to get the output format requested in your question:

```
{ cat iw_output; cat iwinfo_output; } |
awk 'match($0,/([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}/,a) && !seen[a[0]]++{printf "%s\"%s\"", (c++?OFS:""), a[0]} END{print ""}'
"01:23:45:67:89:AB" "CD:EF:A0:A1:A2:A3"
```

With other awks you'd use `substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)` instead of `a[0]`.

Comment: Thank you Ed, this one is the one I was looking for! I had to use substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) instead of a[0] as you suggested. May I know how to remove the leading space in front of the output using the awk? I was able to achieve it with sed only. Thank you. Btw I have never thought this can be achieved with the awk only. You have my admiration :D

Comment: Change `++c` to `c++` so `c` is zero first time it's tested. I've updated my answer to do that, it was a bug. You're welcome. You can do any text manipulation with awk only, it is an extremely powerful and concise tool/language designed for manipulating text. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

If you want to make the outputs unique, you would run the result of the commands in my original answer through `sort` and `uniq`:

```
{ iw ...; iwinfo ...; } | grep -Eo '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' | sort | uniq
```

If you then wanted to wrap them in double quotes and replace the newline with a space, you would do:

```
{ iw ...; iwinfo ...; } | grep -Eo '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' | sort | uniq | sed -E 's|(.*)|"\1"|' | tr '\n' ' '

"01:23:45:67:89:AB" "CD:EF:A0:A1:A2:A3"
```

**Original Answer**

I am confused by your question,  but I think this will do what you want:

```
{ iw dev wlan0 scan 2>/dev/null; iwinfo wlan0 scan; } | grep -Eo '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

**Sample Output**

```
01:23:45:67:89:AB
CD:EF:A0:A1:A2:A3
01:23:45:67:89:AB
CD:EF:A0:A1:A2:A3
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works the best. How can I make the command to grab only unique BSSIDs? I've got some duplicates in the output. Maybe that is why awk is used along with !seen[$0]. So what I need: unique items & exactly the same format of the output: "01:23:45:67:89:AB" "CD:EF:A0:A1:A2:A3" ... - like in the first post. Please keep also this one format for further reference (in case you decide to edit it). Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Mark, you have saved my day. Now I can fully rewrite the script for using BSSIDs instead of ESSIDs and make use of disable SSID broadcast feature. Please also provide me with a good documentation or maybe better literature. I am quite good with regexes, but I am not familiar with those [:notations:]. Sort and uniq looks cool, never thought about them. The main point was to write this app with awk, but I think that I give up to awk and stick with the sed. Thank you once again for your gorgeous help! :)

Answer (score 1):

@Martin: Try:

```
Your_command | awk -vs1="\"" '/^Cell/{VAL=VAL?VAL s1 $NF s1:s1 $NF s1} END{print VAL}'
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tried pretty much every solution here -
none of them worked for me, it seems the best idea is to run:

wsl --unregister kali-linux

and then install it again via the microsoft store.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).